# confusion on module vs state

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

i am a beginner at MEAN.JS. I am a bit confused about few of the things.

Case: i want to create a page which can be opened at url [xxxx.com/post-requirement]
the contents of this page will store data to DB on submit

which thing should i follow:
1) create a module by the name 'post-requirement'
or
2) create a state using ui-router

the second case is easy but because i am working in the 'core' module, the boilerplate did not provide model files from where i can store info into mongodb and i dont how to create them.

please suggest.

Comment: i am using meanjs boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the former just to keep from adding too much to the core module. If you include the Articles module in the boilerplate app you create it will give you a models file and other assets to use as a guide. Just create a file similar to the articles model in your new module and change names accordingly.